# Count number of files in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to count the files in the folder to get the total length

Now I have got one config factory with length static

```
App.factory('srConfig', function() {
return {
    LENGTH: 9,
    getFileFromId: function(id) {
        if (id < 10) {
            id = '0' + id;
        }
        return './data/data/sr-' + id + '.json';
    }
};
```

})

Call to factory config

```
App.factory('srProvider', function(srConfig, $q, $http) {
return {
    getList: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var sr = [];
        for (var currentId = 1; currentId <= srConfig.LENGTH; currentId++) {
            sr.push($http.get(srConfig.getFileFromId(currentId)));
        };

        $q.all(sr).then(function(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            deferred.reject(error);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    },
    get: function(id) {
        return $http.get(srConfig.getFileFromId(id));
    }
}
```

})

Comment: What's the question? Is it working? Is it not?

Comment: Its works but need get a dynamic length not 9 all time I need to count the Number of archives un that folder ./data/data/ARCHIVES and insert in length the number of files. I don't know how to count the number and how to give that value to app factory config